# Filtering array of objects which contain arrays

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like this:

```
const arr = [
  {
    birth_year: '19BBY',
    gender: 'male',
    height: '172',
    name: 'Luke Skywalker',
    titles: [
      'Revenge of the Sith',
      'A New Hope',
      'The Empire Strikes Back',
      'Return of the Jedi',
    ],
  },
  {
    gender: 'n/a',
    height: '167',
    name: 'C-3PO',
    titles: [
      'The Phantom Menace',
      'Attack of the Clones',
      'Revenge of the Sith',
      'A New Hope',
      'The Empire Strikes Back',
      'Return of the Jedi',
    ],
  },
  {
    birth_year: '33BBY',
    gender: 'n/a',
    height: '96',
    name: 'R2-D2',
    titles: [
      'The Phantom Menace',
      'Attack of the Clones',
      'Revenge of the Sith',
      'A New Hope',
      'The Empire Strikes Back',
      'Return of the Jedi',
    ],
  },
];
```

I want to filter it by titles. So for example, if I'll filter by **Attack of the Clones**

```
const test = arr.map(({ titles }) =>
      titles.filter((title) => title === 'Attack of the Clones')
    );
```

But in return, I'm getting only this:

```
[[], ['Attack of the Clones'], ['Attack of the Clones']];
```

instead of all objects (C-3PO, R2-D2) that contain **Attack of the Clones** in their titles array.

Comment: You're extracting the titles and then return the result of filtering them. First `.filter()` the array (`arr`) by title (`.some()`) then extract the name and return it (`.map()`)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
arr.filter(el => el.titles.includes('Attack of the Clones'));
```

or, using destructuring

```
arr.filter(({titles}) => titles.includes('Attack of the Clones'));
```

Comment: It works, but I have to type in my input "Attack of the Clones" to find it. Can I make something to type just "Attack" or "Att" to find "Attack of the Clones"?

Comment: For this, you could perhaps use `arr.filter(el => el.titles.some((title) => title.includes(searchStr)))` - Where searchStr in the string you typed in.

Answer (score -1):

One liner:

```js
const arr = [
  {
    birth_year: '19BBY',
    gender: 'male',
    height: '172',
    name: 'Luke Skywalker',
    titles: [
      'Revenge of the Sith',
      'A New Hope',
      'The Empire Strikes Back',
      'Return of the Jedi',
    ],
  },
  {
    gender: 'n/a',
    height: '167',
    name: 'C-3PO',
    titles: [
      'The Phantom Menace',
      'Attack of the Clones',
      'Revenge of the Sith',
      'A New Hope',
      'The Empire Strikes Back',
      'Return of the Jedi',
    ],
  },
  {
    birth_year: '33BBY',
    gender: 'n/a',
    height: '96',
    name: 'R2-D2',
    titles: [
      'The Phantom Menace',
      'Attack of the Clones',
      'Revenge of the Sith',
      'A New Hope',
      'The Empire Strikes Back',
      'Return of the Jedi',
    ],
  },
];

const result = arr.map(i => i.titles.find(e => e === 'Attack of the Clones') && i.name).filter(Boolean)
// Or if you want it as a function call:
const getTitle = (title) => arr.map(i => i.titles.find(e => e === title) && i.name).filter(Boolean)
console.log(result, getTitle('Attack of the Clones'))
```

**EDIT:**
Since you are referring to obtaining just a string and later the whole object (and I provided the solution for the string), to return the whole object:

```
const result = arr.map(i => i.titles.find(e => e === 'Attack of the Clones') && i).filter(Boolean)
```

Comment: OP wants the full objects, not only the `name` keys.

Comment: @connexo incorrect. That's what he wrote: `I should get only C-3PO and R2-D2 in return.` In any case, to get the whole object you change ` ...&& i.name` with ` && i`

Comment: Consider reading all of the question: *But in return, I'm getting only this:

`[[], ['Attack of the Clones'], ['Attack of the Clones']];`

instead of all **objects** (C-3PO, R2-D2) **that contain** Attack of the Clones **in their titles array***.